# mongoimport Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers hosted on google compute

Tags: json, mongodb, google-compute-engine, mongoimport

I am using the code below to try and import a json array of json documents. Whatever I do I get the error in the title. I am using a replica set named `rs0`. I am running the command from the `gcompute` instance running the `mongod` service. I tried to use both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` as the local host seed. And the ip for the second replica member. As well as the external ip of the localhost.

```
mongoimport --db <db_name> --collection <collection_name> --username <uname> --password <pass> --host rs0/[ip_of_other_replica_member:27017],[127.0.0.1:27017] --type json --file "/tmp/json_backup_wilf17/json_array (10).json" --jsonArray --authenticationDatabase <db_name(same as --db)>
```

as mentioned I keep getting **Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers** .

mongod is running. I can log into the mongo shell. I tried using `rs.slaveOk()` and am now officialy out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I got myself into this situation now as well (manually created cluster) when forgetting the `rs.initiate()` call.

Try checking that you actually have a replica set configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time looking at this, it was the most idiotic of reasons:

> --file "/tmp/json_backup_wilf17/json_array (10).json"

notice the space between the 'y' in 'array and the '(' in '(`10)' ? eliminate it and it will work.

It's a matter of ambiguous error on behalf of Mongodb